# Timespan Compare

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have following time samples:

```
06:09
08:10
23:12
00:06   // next day
00:52
```

I have a sample `00:31` (`nextday`) that needs to be compared and check if its less then the above samples.

```
if (cdnTime > nextNode)
{
   //dosomething
 }
```

`cdnTime` here is the `00:31` and nextNode is the above given multiple samples. Time `00:31` is greater then all samples except `00:52` so I need the if statement to be false until it reaches `00:52`. How do I achieve this. Keeping in mind the time samples switch to next day, do I need to make it as DateTime and then compare or is there any way of comparison with TimeSpan without dates.

Comment: Do you have the entire date available, or only the `TimeSpan`? Do you have any control over how that `TimeSpan` is calculated? The goal would be to make the values meaningful instead of having a value that could mean one of two things and you have to guess which one it means.

Comment: Do you need to parse the timestamps? And how should your program determine if it
's the next or the current day?

Comment: A DateTime should include both the Date and the Time.   You may only be seeing the time portion or the DateTime could be wrong and is missing the Date portion.  When you compare two DateTime objects the compare method automatically compares both the Date and Time.

Comment: Determination for next day is not imp. But if its necessary to do it then I can convert it to datetime which will be easier to compare. Is there any solution to compare with only time samples

Comment: @jdweng you are right but i have to convert them to datetime. But i need to know if without converting can i compare my timesamples

Comment: A TimeSpan is **not** the same as time of day. It's a duration. the .Net framework does not have a type for time of day (but Noda time does). Without the date portion of the DateTime, `00:31` is less than `06:09`.

Comment: How do you consistently determine when one day switches into the next? Here we see that `23:12` goes to `00:06`, so we can see that it has switched over to another day, but what if it went `20:17 21:18` where each was a different day? Given the range of values, I'm assuming that this is possible?

Comment: Yes if you are tracking hours greater than 24.  A timespan is designed to handle "double TotalDays { get; }"  A double is a very large number and not just one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to somehow tell that it's another day. You can either use a DateTime, but you could also initialize a timespan with an additional day - it provides a [Parse-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) for this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;             

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cdnTime = TimeSpan.Parse("23:12", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var nextTime = TimeSpan.Parse("01.00:03", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine(cdnTime.TotalMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine(nextTime.TotalMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine(cdnTime.CompareTo(nextTime));
        Console.WriteLine(cdnTime < nextTime);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to add the day afterwards:

```
var anotherTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
anotherTime = anotherTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));        
Console.WriteLine(anotherTime.TotalMinutes);
```

You can try it out here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/k39TIe

Comment: Perfect, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is what I was missing. After adding that it's working fine. Thanks